# React: document.getElementById (or onClick) does not work

Tags: reactjs, onclick, getelementbyid

I want a random number to be generated and put into the "roomid" input field once the "generate" button is clicked, but the value shown is still 0 after I clicked the button. It guess it is not the problem of onClick because there was indeed a "?" added to the URL after I clicked the button. What is wrong with the code? Thank you so much for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzcbx.png)

Comment: Please include code as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: You can use react.js onClick event  instead of javascript document.onClick. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

React way of doing something like this would be

```
class StartStream extends Component {
  state = { randomId: 0 }

  generate = () => {
    this.setState({ randomId: Math.random() * 1000 });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.randomId} />
      <button onClick={this.generate}>Generate</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Here is a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/tfc3javx/1/